# how can I add more character space to the home page tagline in big cartel?

Tags: bigcartel

Does anyone know how to edit the CSS in a Big Cartel theme (specifically the FOUNDRY theme) to allow for more text in the home page tagline? Currently, you can only type about 100 characters. I would like to be able to write a bit more (like a small paragraph about the shop and current product overview).

Answer (score 0):

The text box is limited to 100 characters, so to edit that you'll need to change the code the Advanced > Home section of the Customize Design area. Find this code at the top:

```
{% if theme.home_tagline != blank %}
  <div class="home_tagline">
    {{ theme.home_tagline }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

And replace the `{{ theme.home_tagline }}` with your own text.